# What am I missing here? Apache keeps serving default page

Tags: django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have configured my Django site but Apache keeps serving the default apache's page. What am I missing here? My setup is Django 1.10 on CentOS server with python3.5.

### Project structure

```
/home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal
    requirements.txt
    src
        manage.py
        media
        sbsportal
            __init__.py
            __pycache__
            settings.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
        static
        templates
    venv
```

### /etc/httpd/conf.d/sbsportal.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@email.com
  ServerName sbsportal
  ServerAlias sbsportal.com
  DocumentRoot /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/

  WSGIDaemonProcess sbsportal python-path=/home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src:/home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  WSGIApplicationGroup sbsportal
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/sbsportal/wsgi.py process-group=djangoproj

  <Directory /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/sbsportal>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  Alias /static /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/static
  <Directory /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/static>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /static /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/templates
  <Directory /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/templates>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /media /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/media
  <Directory /home/sbsadmin/web/sbsportal/src/media>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

### wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for sbsportal project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sbsportal.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### Settings.py

```
.
.
.
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
.
.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I have resolved pretty much all the problems. Only thin is that now I am seeing `403 forbidden error`.

Comment: Have you enabled the site in Apache?

Comment: @tobassist mmmmm I don't think so. How can I do that? Didn't anything than above mentioned Sir.

Comment: a2ensite wsgi.conf

Comment: @AndreyShipilov a2ensite is not available in CentOS.

Comment: Then this `ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/wsgi.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link â/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.confâ: File exists`

Comment: FYI, I have wsgi.conf sitting in /etc/httpd/conf.d. I just created sites-available and sites-enabled folders. Don't know what to do with them :)

Comment: sites-available etc is a Debian thing; CentOS is not based on that distro, so those directories won't be used.

Comment: I have updated the question. Now seeing 403 permission error.

Comment: You need to provide the actual error from the Apache error log file as to why 403 is being returned, if it is Apache generating it. It usually is one of a few different possible errors. Most common is that Apache user cannot see inside your home directory. Better not to have your stuff under a home directory.

Comment: Also recommended that instead of ``WSGIApplicationGroup sbsportal`` you have ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``.

Comment: Where you have option ``process-group=djangoproj`` to ``WSGIScriptAlias``, it should be ``process-group=sbsportal``. This could be the source of the 403. The error in Apache logs would confirm it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton My mod_wsgi is unable to load. I am using python3.5 with Apache 2.2. Here is my output of ldd `ldd mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa7983000)
        libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00007f0e4b6aa000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0e4b48d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0e4b288000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0e4b085000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0e4ae01000)

`
How do I compile mod_wsgi for 3.5?

Comment: See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi. Use the pip install method and then follow instructions in last section about connecting result of that into an existing Apache installation. That is easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added selinux context in your project diretory ? if not do the following :

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/home/sbsadmin/myproject/(/.*)'

restorecon -Rv /home/sbsadmin/myproject/
```

Or try disabling selinux `setenforce 0`

Comment: Oh man this resolved the issue for me. :) Thanks a lot. I can see django website now. Can you please explain what exactly it is? I may not be given permission to turn it off in work production environment.

Comment: You're the most welcome ^^. Its not recommneded to disable selinux, you have to add the httpd context to your directory project. Take a look at this http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/